# Can I overlap Firestore security rules to prevent the use of the OR operator everywhere?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a bunch of collections to define security rules for and they all have logical `OR` operators in them to account for admin rights. Here is one such example:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        function isAdmin() {
            return request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/userProfiles/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
        }

        function isSignedIn() {
            return request.auth != null;
        }

        function isOwnDocument() {
            return request.auth.uid == request.resource.id
        }

        match /userSettings/{doc} {
            allow read: if isOwnDocument() || isAdmin();
            allow write: if isOwnDocument() || isAdmin();
        }
    }
}
```

Could I, instead, declare admin rights up front and omit the `OR` operator?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        function isAdmin() {
            return request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/userProfiles/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
        }

        function isSignedIn() {
            return request.auth != null;
        }

        function isOwnDocument() {
            return request.auth.uid == request.resource.id
        }

        match /{document=**} {
            allow read: if isAdmin();
            allow write: if isAdmin();
        }

        match /userSettings/{doc} {
            allow read: if isOwnDocument();
            allow write: if isOwnDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

Would this be a good practice?

Comment: wow that's lucrative, I can't quickly answer because I haven't tried (and will do so now), but I want to let you know that you can use the console's rule editor to test such rules and see if it will work. then secondly you can set admin through customClaims and access it in auth.token instead of the way you are doing.

Comment: I will back let me test and give you feedback

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude can you elaborate on what you mean by setting admin through custom claims?

Comment: I will explain in answer, I'm typing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I, instead, declare admin rights up front and omit the OR operator?

Yes!

I just checked the Rules Playground in the Firebase Console.

[image]

To try the Rules Playground, [go to the Rules tab of Cloud Firestore](https://console.firebase.google.com/_/genesysaefunai/firestore/rules) and click on Rules Playground. You will see it bottom left to the Rules Editor. There, you can build the data and an authenticated state and from there simulate a request.

> Would this be a good practice?

Yes, certainly. It will make your Firestore Rules cleaner. So you won't need to be putting `||` (or) in every match.

##### Explanation

[From the Firebase Docs:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements)

> It's possible for a document to match more than one match statement. In the case where multiple allow expressions match a request, the access is allowed if any of the conditions is true

So when `isAdmin()` is true (and because it is declared upfront for all documents), Firestore will allow access for the documents.

##### From the question comments ...

> can you elaborate on what you mean by setting admin through custom claims?

[Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) is a feature in Firebase where you can assign different roles to users. You can use custom claims to set admin privileges, teacher permissions, or any role your app needs.

Custom Claims take valid JSON (preferably key-value pairs with boolean values).

Custom Claims on a user can be accessed in different parts of Firebase:

1. In the clients, through `idToken`,
2. In the admin SDK, through `auth.token`, and
3. In the security rules (for Firestore, Realtime Database, and Storage).

So, in either of these parts of Firebase, you can check the custom claims on an authenticated user to give them access to resources or not.

Note that custom claims are not meant to be used as a store of data to extend the User object from Firebase Authentication. They are primarily there for security rules. Firebase will reject custom claims that are more than 1000 bytes.

Also, you can only manage custom claims on your projects in the admin SDK.

Learn about custom claims [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

Comment: Can you set custom claims through the web console or must some script execute it?

Comment: you can't set through the web console either. You must set it to through admin SDK. So maybe you have to write cloud functions or create your own custom backend and connect firebase, then set the custom claims there.

Comment: It might be tough for you given that it seems like you have gone far with the project but if you plan it well and understand you will get it right, you can also check youtube for steps to go about this.

Comment: And for the `isAdmin()` function, wouldn't just `return request.auth.token.admin;` be enough?

Comment: it would be enough. but for it to work, you must have made sure that you have set {"admin": true} as the customClaims object on the users that are admins through the admin SDK.